# FreeBSD does not boot after power loss/upgrade/ever? (ntpd issue...)

Tags: freebsd, corruption

(**Edit:** leaving the original question for background; skip down to below the divider if you aren't interested.)

My residence recently experienced a power outage. Unfortunately, as I was out at the time, I was not able to cleanly shut down my system before the UPS ran out of battery.

My Linux machine seems fine, but my FreeBSD (12.1) machine won't boot. Instead of a login prompt, it drops me straight into an unprivaleged shell that won't even let me `su`.

I have inspected both the tty boot messages (as best I can, given that they scroll away) as well as `/var/log/messages`, but the only potential indications of a problem are:

- An angry beep (lower and slightly longer than the POST beep)
- An error message about "MSI-X tables"
- `/` is mounted read-only

I've manually run `fsck` (booting in single-user mode seems to work okay, except the system isn't really usable like that) is clean. I'm running a zpool scrub on the storage array (the OS is on UFS, but this box is essentially a NAS) but don't anticipate any errors. Other than some open sshfs connections, the system would not have been doing anything at the time it lost power.

Other notes:

- The system was originally installed as FreeBSD 12.0, and it's quite possible it has never been booted since upgrading.
- The root FS mounts and "looks" intact. (Read: I ran `ls` on a couple directories and expected files seem to be present.
- I've installed some stuff from ports (mostly GNU CLI tools), but AFAIK no kmods or anything like that. The system is a fairly basic budget AMD+APU.
- It appears that all physical keypresses are being recorded in `/var/log/messages`?

What could be wrong?

---

**Edit:** Well... I'm *sort of* an idiot, although this is still a WTF? situation. However, I'm now less certain the machine hasn't been doing this since installation; now that I realize what's happening, I think I've seen this before, so it probably has nothing to do with the power loss. (Did I mention it doesn't get rebooted often?)

I finally noticed something funny about the shell I was getting dumped in. Can you spot it? Here's the last few lines after boot:

```
Updating motd:.
Mounting late filesystems:.
Security policy loaded: MAC/ntpd (mac_ntpd)
Starting ntpd.
[ntpd@<redacted> /]$ █
```

...and that's it; no login, no errors, no network, just the completely nerfed command prompt shown above.

So *why* the heck is it doing this? (Hint: ^D "fixes" it, as you might expect if you've noticed what's wrong, but *why* does it do this? I'd like my system to boot up without needing its hand held! I suspect this also means I have a non-working daemon .)

Comment: Usually you can press scroll lock and then page up/down to inspect all the messages. FreeBSD does not drop to emergency shell without a proper hint what's going on.

Comment: @MartinSugioarto, "does not drop to emergency shell without a proper hint", want to bet?  Okay, well, the hint is subtle, and it's technically not an *emergency* shell... I *sort of* figured out what's going on. Stay tuned for an update. (BTW, thanks for the scroll-lock tip!)

Comment: It looks weird. Did you change the ntpd startup script or used weird parameters? It looks like somewhere an interactive shell is started with `ntpd` as user.

Comment: Right, I finally figured out the second part. As for the first, not to my knowledge. The only thing I can think of that *might* be weird is that I have a bunch of BSD programs path-replaced with GNU equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this, but one of the simplest is to botch the `ntpd_flags` setting in `/etc/rc.conf` and effectively perform a command injection attack upon onesself.

This is why `rc` systems based upon shell script are so hard to get right.  It is *very* difficult to *thoroughly* defend against all of the ways in which extra shell commands can be (accidentally) injected, especially when `printf` lacks a `%q` format specifier.

FreeBSD's Mewburn `rc` scripts have not been defensively coded against such accidents pretty much at all.  Notice that a `ntpd_config` filename won't work if it contains whitespace, for example.  That's a fairly trivial piece of quoting compared to some.

And yes, this is not an emergency shell.

Comment: The only ntdp-related thing in `/etc/rc.conf` is `ntpd_enable="YES"`... AFAIK, I haven't done *anything whatsoever* to fiddle with the config.

Comment: The problem is in this command: `limits -C daemon su -m ntpd -c 'sh -c "/usr/sbin/ntpd  -p /var/db/ntp/ntpd.pid -c /etc/ntp.conf -f /var/db/ntp/ntpd.drift"'`. Same effect running that at a shell. Doesn't look obviously fishy; any guesses?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, esoterica (also, things I loathe about BSD).

The default shell on FreeBSD is (t?)csh. I hate [t]csh. So, I stuck a line in `.cshrc` to exec to bash instead.

Problem: now any shell run "as" root (n.b. `su -m`) is incapable of accepting a command argument; it will just exec (an interactive!) bash instead.

Solution: exec bash in `.login` (which is apparently csh-specific) instead.

Comment: You should have read about the command `chsh` and also why never change the root shell to anything else than `sh`. Please use an unprivileged user for optional shells.

Comment: And if you still insist on have a super user (root) with a different shell then do it for the `toor` user. It still has `uid 0` and can then keep `root` clean.